why is my connection string deployed as blank through an ARM and CICD?
My azure function has an arm template with a connectionStrings section:
      ],
      "connectionStrings":[            
        {
          "name":"ConnectionString",
          "value":"[parameters('ConnectionString')]"
        }
      ]

I'm using an ARM Template deployment and overriding the parameter like so:

When I look at the portal to see how it was deployed, I'm seeing that it is blank and labeled as MySQL (even though this is a sql server connection string)

This connection string is stored as a secret inside the of the release pipeline variables:
Server=tcp:sxxxxxxxxx-dev-centralus-001.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxxx-dev-centralus-001;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;Authentication=\"Active Directory Default\";

Why is the connection string deployed as blank?

You need to provide us more details about the pipeline and the secret, including (but not limited to): what is the scope of the secret (stage, pipeline)? Are you using multiple stages? ...

Hi @AlexGordon, May I know the answer below can resolve your question in this thread? Thx for taking time to share the update.

I have successfully added the SQL connection string via Azure Devops Release pipeline by referring the steps below:-
My azuredeploy.json:-
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "functionAppName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[format('func-{0}', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the Azure Function app."
      }
    },
    "storageAccountType": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Standard_LRS",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Standard_LRS",
        "Standard_GRS",
        "Standard_RAGRS"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Storage Account type"
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for all resources."
      }
    },
    "functionWorkerRuntime": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "node",
      "allowedValues": [
        "dotnet",
        "node",
        "python",
        "java"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The language worker runtime to load in the function app."
      }
    },
    "packageUri": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The zip content url."
      }
    },
    "ConnectionString": {
      "type": "securestring",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The connection string for your database."
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "hostingPlanName": "[parameters('functionAppName')]",
    "applicationInsightsName": "[parameters('functionAppName')]",
    "storageAccountName": "[format('{0}azfunctions', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2022-05-01",
      "name": "[variables('storageAccountName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('storageAccountType')]"
      },
      "kind": "Storage"
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
      "name": "[variables('hostingPlanName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Y1",
        "tier": "Dynamic",
        "size": "Y1",
        "family": "Y"
      },
      "properties": {
        "computeMode": "Dynamic"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
      "apiVersion": "2020-02-02",
      "name": "[variables('applicationInsightsName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "tags": {
        "[format('hidden-link:{0}', resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('applicationInsightsName')))]": "Resource"
      },
      "properties": {
        "Application_Type": "web"
      },
      "kind": "web"
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
      "name": "[parameters('functionAppName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "kind": "functionapp",
      "properties": {
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('hostingPlanName'))]",
        "siteConfig": {
          "appSettings": [
            {
              "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
              "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('applicationInsightsName')), '2020-02-02').InstrumentationKey]"
            },
            {
              "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
              "value": "[format('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={0};EndpointSuffix={1};AccountKey={2}', variables('storageAccountName'), environment().suffixes.storage, listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), '2021-09-01').keys[0].value)]"
            },
            {
              "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
              "value": "[format('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={0};EndpointSuffix={1};AccountKey={2}', variables('storageAccountName'), environment().suffixes.storage, listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), '2021-09-01').keys[0].value)]"
            },
            {
              "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
              "value": "[toLower(parameters('functionAppName'))]"
            },
            {
              "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
              "value": "~4"
            },
            {
              "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
              "value": "[parameters('functionWorkerRuntime')]"
            },
            {
              "name": "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION",
              "value": "~14"
            },
            {
              "name": "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE",
              "value": "1"
            }
          ],
          "connectionStrings": [
            {
              "name": "ConnectionString",
              "connectionString": "[parameters('ConnectionString')]",
              "type": "SQLAzure"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('applicationInsightsName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('hostingPlanName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName'))]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/extensions",
      "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
      "name": "[format('{0}/{1}', parameters('functionAppName'), 'zipdeploy')]",
      "properties": {
        "packageUri": "[parameters('packageUri')]"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('functionAppName'))]"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

My azuredeploy.parameters.json:-
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "functionAppName": {
      "value": "valleyfunc763"
    },
    "storageAccountType": {
      "value": "Standard_LRS"
    },
    "location": {
      "value": "AustraliaEast"
    },
    "functionWorkerRuntime": {
      "value": "node"
    },
    "packageUri": {
      "value": "https://github.com/xxxxx/azurefuncHTTP"
    },
    "ConnectionString": {
      "value": "$(ConnectionString)"
    }
  }
}

My Azure Devops Release pipeline with Override template:-

-functionAppName "valleydesai561" -storageAccountType "Standard_LRS" -location "AustraliaEast" -functionWorkerRuntime "node" -packageUri "https://github.com/xxxxxxxxxx/azurefuncHTTP" -ConnectionString "$(ConnectionString)"

Release pipeline variables:-

Name: ConnectionString
Value:Server=tcp:valleyserversql87.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=valleydb54;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=xxxxx;Password=xxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;

Output:-
SQL Connection string added successfully after release in Azure Functions app:-


I think you didn't define the template properly. According to the documentation it should look something like this,
...   
"connectionStrings": [
    {
      "name": "ConnectionString",
      "connectionString": "[parameters('ConnectionString')]",
      "type": "SQL Server type"
...

not name and value.
then define your sql server type in the type section.
